# How to inspect the interface of a template template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, template-templates

I was trying to overload a template class with SFINAE based on whether a template template parameter had the type `type` defined in it (for example `std::remove_reference` has a `type` member type alias), but I cannot figure out a good way to go about doing that.

For example, I wanted to do

```
template <template <typename...> class Trait>
using EnableIfHasTypeMember = std::void_t<Trait::type>;

template <template <typename...> class Trait, typename OtherStuff,
          EnableIfHasTypeMember<Trait>* = nullptr>
class Something { ... }
```

But this gives me a compiler error.  Is there any way I can go about inspecting the interface of a template template parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're wanting, it's not possible with the level of generality that you showed in your example. You can't know whether the template has a type member type alias unless you know the arguments it's instantiated with, because it could differ based on the specialization. Example:

```
template <typename T>
struct my_trait
{
    using type = int;
};

template <>
struct my_trait<double> {};
```

How would you expect `EnableIfHasTypeMember` to behave in this case? That's why you can't reason about the contents of a template until it is instantiated.

It helps in situations like this to keep in mind that all instantiations of `my_trait<T>` for different types `T` **are distinct types from one another**. There is no actual relationship between the types; they originated from a common template, which admits the ability to write a generic implementation that is reused, but the concrete types once instantiated are wholly separate.

Answer (score 1):

@Jason R is correct, you can't do this at the class template level.

If you are wanting to detect class templates with `type` members, you have to provide arguments to get a specific type, to inspect the members of.

Adapting [an example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)

```
// primary template handles types that have no nested ::type member:
template< class, class = std::void_t<> >
struct has_type_member : std::false_type { };

// specialization recognizes types that do have a nested ::type member:
template< class T >
struct has_type_member<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>> : std::true_type { };

// specialization recognizes class templates that do have a nested ::type member:
template< template< class ... > class T, class ... Args >
struct has_type_member<T<Args...>, std::void_t<typename T<Args...>::type>> : std::true_type { };
```